# How to sort a list of strings by size first, then alphabetically

Tags: sorting, elixir

I'm trying to sort a list of strings, first by size then alphabetically. Before I started, this is what I had:

```
Enum.sort( &(byte_size(&1) > byte_size(&2)) )
```

What I wanted to create, was something like this:

```
Enum.sort( fn(a, b) -> byte_size(a) > byte_size(b) && String.compare(a, b) > 0 end)
```

However, the String module doesn't have a means to test whether one string is greater than the other. There's `String.equivalent?` but that returns whether a string is equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume from your example, you want to sort in decending order... This is probably the most succinct approach:

```
iex(10)> ~w(hello is it what you want) |> Enum.sort(fn
...(10)>   s1, s2 when byte_size(s1) == byte_size(s2) -> s1 > s2
...(10)>   s1, s2 -> byte_size(s1) > byte_size(s2)
...(10)> end)
```

This may not give you the results if your dealing with Unicode. So you this may be a better approach.

```
iex(11)> ~w(hello is it what you want) |> Enum.sort(fn s1, s2 ->
...(11)>   len1 = String.length(s1)
...(11)>   len2 = String.length(s2)
...(11)>   if len1 == len2, do: s1 > s2, else: len1 > len2
...(11)> end)
["hello", "what", "want", "you", "it", "is"]
iex(12)>
```

Comment: I think you can shorten the fn to `{byte_size(s1), s1} > {byte_size(s2), s2}` (haven't tested).